# TypeScript Express routes

Tags: typescript, express

I am following a tutorial from [Building a Node.js App with TypeScript Tutorial](https://blog.risingstack.com/building-a-node-js-app-with-typescript-tutorial/). I want to seperate the routes. So I tried to create a route folder and created a test.ts file with below content:

```js
import {Router} from "express";

let router = Router();
router.get('/', get);
/**
 * GET /
 * @param req
 * @param res
 * @param next
 */
export async function get(req, res, next) {
    try {
        res.send("Testing...");
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('err', err);
        next(err);
    }
}

export {router};
```

Now I am trying to use it in server.ts files as below :

```js
import * as express from "express";
import * as TestRoute from './routes/test';

class App {
    public express : express.Application;

    constructor() {
        this.express = express();
        this.mountRoutes();
    }

    private mountRoutes() : void {
        const routes: express.Router = express.Router();
        routes.use('/test', TestRoute);
        this.express.use('/', routes);
    }
}

export default new App().express;
```

But in this line `routes.use('/test', TestRoute);` TypeScript is throwing an error :

`Argument of type ... is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandlerParams'.
Argument of type ... is not assignable to type '(RequestHandler | ErrorRequestHandler)[]'.
Property 'includes' is missing in type ...`

... is the path to my test.ts file.

Could anybody help me identify what is this error and also can you give me a basic structure of creating routes and including it in TypeScript Apps. I am using TypeScript 2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the import in the server.ts file, well more specific it's how you're using the module.

If you have a look at the TestRoute object, it's actually just a module and which contains everything you've exported. So you need to access the `router` object somehow. This can be done in two ways.

1. Change your import in your server.ts to `import { router as TestRoute } from './routes/test';`
2. Alternatively you can change how you access the module in your `routes.use` line by changing this to `routes.use('/test', TestRoute.router);`

Either option will work, but you only need to use one!